# SBT: execute task using other task value

Tags: scala, build, sbt, sbt-0.13

I redefine my tests to supply some arguments from configuration to test suite:

This is an excerpt from my Build.scala:

```
object Build extends Build {
  lazy val myProject = (project in file("my_project")).settings(
    test in Test := myProjectTest.value
  )

  val myProjectTest = Def.task {
    (testOnly in Test).toTask(" tests.Suites -- " +
      s"-Ddbserver=localhost " +
      s"-Ddbport=3306 ").value
  }
}
```

This works ok.

Now, I wanted to give my test suite the name of an artifact like this:

```
val myProjectTest = Def.task {
  val art = (Keys.artifactPath in (Compile, packageBin)).value

  (testOnly in Test).toTask(" tests.Suites -- " +
    s"-Dartifact=${art.getCanonicalPath} " +
    s"-Ddbserver=localhost " +
    s"-Ddbport=3306").value
}
```

But it shows the following error message:

```
[error] /tmp/aa/project/Build.scala:17: Illegal dynamic reference: art
[error]     s"-Dartifact=${art.getCanonicalPath} " +
[error]                    ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

I know **something** about SBT internals, macros, task dependency graph, and I even managed to solve some of my tasks using scopes. Here I tried to use map or flatMap on `(Keys.artifactPath in (Compile, packageBin))` but cannot achieve the desirted result. Whenever I try to access `.value` I get `Illegal dynamic reference`.

Please, guide me. I just need to pass the value of task to other task (inputKey) parameters.

SBT version: **0.13.5**

Comment: Writing code, which works and helps to reproduce the problem would dramatically help to get an answer to your problem.

Comment: This is the code. I don't expect any research effort, and any sbt user who wrote custom builds will rather find information sufficient. Your negative vote decreases my chances to get a quick answer, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By trial and error I've done what I wanted eventually using `Def.taskDyn` (dynamic task):

```
object Build extends Build {
  lazy val myProject = (project in file("my_project")).settings(
    test in Test := myProjectTest.value
  )

  lazy val myProjectTest = Def.taskDyn {
    val art = (Keys.artifactPath in (Compile, packageBin)).value

    (testOnly in Test).toTask(" tests.Suites -- " +
      s"-Dartifact=${art.getCanonicalPath} " +
      s"-Ddbserver=localhost " +
      s"-Ddbport=3306")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen specifying test options via `.toTask`.

Do you want to see if `testOptions in Test` works for you? See the [Options](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html#Options) section of the Testing docs.

Comment: The thing is that I generate arguments dynamically, I just omitted it from question as not relevant. I read some file in `project` directory and pass values to test suite. I don't know if testOptions will fit.